# i am facing a problem when i am installing npm install react-router.dom ...and i am getting a error

Tags: reactjs

PS C:\Users\lonar\Downloads\todos-list\src\MyComponents> npm install react-router.dom

npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-router.dom - Not found

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404  'react-router.dom@*' is not in this registry.

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no library called `react-router.dom`. You need to install `npm install react-router-dom`